# URL fragment being sent to server on iOS 10.0.2 Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

This should not be possible, right?

[whatsmybrowser.org/b/X5USL5N](http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/b/X5USL5N)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what happened was that the link (which was shared on Skype) had it's `#` encoded to `%23` and was therefore still sent to the server.  Apache decoded it and displayed the error as `/#/` instead of `/%23/`

So probably a Skype/iOS bug.