# Why URL fragment is being sent to server?

Tags: url, browser

I have some links in the pages of a website that has a fragment in the href like:

`<a href="#some-fragment">some text</a>`

For some reason I've started to find many errors in logs that alert me about many requests that haven't matched a route on the application. Checking out log's info, I've found that the URL registered in the error has an URL fragment (which means that it has reached server side) and this is what is causing the error.

The only explanation I may found is that the fragment may be encoded as it's explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011586/373622. But I can't imagine why the fragment is being encoded sometimes (when I try to reproduce it by myself, it doesn't happen).

Is there something I'm missing?